# how to check snowflake logging session logs

Tags: logging, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake connectivity issue from python script using RSA keys Error : JWT token is Invalid
my users are facing some issue while connecting to snowflake with customize python script, I have seated RSA key at snowflake end.

to check the exact logs from logging sessions at snowflake end, is there way to check the logs from logging sessions at snowflake end, do we have options ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reach Snowflake support for that kind of logging.

Try testing with SnowSQL as well the key/pair auth and if it's still failing with same error reach out to Snowflake support.

Check also possible causes that are explained [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Key-Based-Authentication-Failed-with-JWT-token-is-invalid-Error)

Comment: Thanks for the reply on above question @Sergiu ! we I will go ahead and try to setup the snowsql and check the logs if any ! thanks again !

Answer (score -1):

glad to share that, JWT token error has been solved after provide  with domain name i.e. foo@example.com. earlier we were using only user id and not domain name.